# Actions in MVC 4 WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have been following http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/tutorial-your-first-web-api and after creating the following controller, I am getting unexpected results...

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    Product[] products = new Product[] 
    { 
        new Product { Id = 1, Name = "Tomato Soup", Category = "Groceries", Price = 1 }, 
        new Product { Id = 2, Name = "Yo-yo", Category = "Toys", Price = 3.75M }, 
        new Product { Id = 3, Name = "Hammer", Category = "Hardware", Price = 16.99M } 
    };

    public IEnumerable<Product> GetAllProducts()
    {
        return products;
    }

    public Product GetProductById(int id)
    {
        var product = products.FirstOrDefault((p) => p.Id == id);
        if (product == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return product;
    }
}
```

I expect to be able to make a call like this:

> /api/products/GetAllProducts

But this does not work.  Instead, I can simply call:

> /api/products

Which actually does the procedure described in `GetAllProducts()`.  Why doesn't this work as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `Url`: `/api/products/GetAllProducts` it does not work because your web Api just only support default routing:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

In order to make it work as your expectation, you need to add one more route to support `action` on top:

```
configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
          name: "CustomizedApi",
          routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
      );
```

As for the second `URL`: `/api/products`, it works because:

The `id` in default route is optional (`RouteParameter.Optional`).

And from the [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-and-action-selection):

> The framework only chooses actions that match the HTTP method (GET, POST, PUT, DELETE) of the request, determined as follows:
>
> - HTTP method with an attribute: AcceptVerbs, HttpDelete, HttpGet,    HttpHead, HttpOptions, HttpPatch, HttpPost, or HttpPut.
> - Otherwise, if the name of the controller method starts with "Get",    "Post", "Put", "Delete", "Head", "Options", or "Patch", then by convention the action supports that HTTP method.
> - If none of the above, the method supports POST.

In your case, if you make a request from browser, it's supposed to be a GET request, so this request will map to the action which starts with `Get` (the method `GetAllProducts`)

Answer (score 3):

Because in the WebApi framework it is *assuming* you want the "Get" method.

Are you familiar with the different http verbs? Post, Get, Put, Delete? When you type a url into your browser it issues a Get request. the framework sees that and assume you want to GetAllProducts.

If you have a DeleteAllProducts, and issued a Delete request to `/api/products` it would run that one.

If you had a `GetProduct(int id)` and issued a Get request (by typing into the browser address bar, for example) to `api/products/1` it would execute `GetProcuct(1)`.

Think of is as more of a CRUD based controller. You could just have actions called Get, Post, Put, Delete and it would run those based on the http verb used.  Want to update a product? It would be something like `public ActionResult Post(int id, [FromBody]Product p)` and you would call it via a POST request to /api/products/1. Of course the Product Json/XML would need to be sent in the request body for serialization to work.

Comment: Details here: [Routing in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: Thanks, @Alex I was looking for something like that to add.